# How to store custom objects with blocks variable in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, objective-c-blocks

i want to store a custom object with a block in NSUserDefaults. I've already implement

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder and - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

is there a way to store myblock variable during this call ?
something like this :

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeSomething:self->_myblock forKey:@"myblock"];
}
```

I've already tried to encodeObjectf and it does not seems to work...
if someone already try this, i might appreciate your help :-)

Elendar.

Comment: Why you wrote `self->_myblock` instead `self._myblock`?

Comment: @CAMOBAP `self->_myblock` is identical to `_myblock` This access an ivar. `self._myblock` is an incorrect attempt to access a property named `_myblock`. The OP is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that's not possible directly. You may do this indirectly, nice solution suggested here: [Is there any way to serialize / unserialize an Objective-C block?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3326124/1032151)

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to searlize data instead of blocks. Create some custom class and searlize your data and on the runtime you can always create the block utilizing that data. AFAIK blocks don't confirms to NSCoding (Correct me if I'm wrong here).

-MANN